# How to store timed passed in NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I want to store the amount of time that has passed within NSDate. So when a button is trigger i want a timer to start counting, i guess in seconds, and then store how much time has passed till the user has hit the next button within NSDate so I can subtract this value from another NSDate to get the difference with a NSTimeInterval.

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(slider.value * 60)];

        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[date timeIntervalSinceNow] target:self selector:@selector(nextFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDate` has an instance method `timeIntervalSinceDate:` that returns an `NSTimeInterval`.
When the first button is pressed, you can get the current data using `[NSDate date]` and store it in a property named 'previousDate', and then when the second button is pressed: You can get the current data again and calculate the time interval that passed using the following code:

```
- (void)firstButtonTapped {
    [self setPreviousDate:[NSDate date]];
}

- (void)secondButtonTapped {
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[self previousDate]];
    // timeInterval now contains the amount of time that passed in seconds
}
```

Comment: Do i create the timer using NSDate though? Could you give me an example with code that will preform the tasks i mentioned. Thanks

Comment: No you set the *previousDate* variable on the first button click; this is a property you store locally in your class. Then when the second button is clicked you create a new date, as shown above, and compare the two and the timeInterval will return the number of seconds that have passed.

Comment: i dont understand the setPreviousDate part.. cant i do something like NSDate *date2 = timeIntervalSinceDate. Look at my code above.

Comment: Im not creating any classes